# How do you interpret the resulting bands of gel zymography?

Tags: proteins, gel-electrophoresis

I would like to clear up some things for gel zymography. I understand that bright bands show proteolytic activity. But which molecular weight do these bands correspond to? Is it the weight of the active enzyme or is it the weight of the digested substrate?